# In the Bernoulli distribution $P(x^{(i)} ; \theta)=\theta^\color{red}{x^{(i)}}(1-\theta)^{(1-\color{red}{x^{(i)}})}$ what does $x^{(i)}$ stand for?

Tags: notation, bernoulli-distribution

I am trying to understand the Bernoulli example for the biais given in [Deep Learning by Bengo et. al.](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html) in 5.4.2:

> Consider a set of samples $\{\color{red}{x^{(1)}, . . . , x^{(m)}}\}$ that are independently and identically distributed according to a Bernoulli distribution with mean $\theta$ : $$ P\left(\color{red}{x^{(i)}} ;
> \theta\right)=\theta^\color{red}{x^{(i)}}(1-\theta)^{\left(1-\color{red}{x^{(i)}}\right)} . $$

I don't get what $x^{(i)}$ are. Indeed I used to remember a Bernoulli distribution probability equation like this one:

$$ P\left(x ; \theta\right)=\theta^{x}(1-\theta)^{\left(1-x\right)}$$

Where we only have two outcomes.

Therefore I don't get the demonstration:

> A common estimator for the $\theta$ parameter of this distribution is the mean of the training samples: $$ \hat{\theta}_m=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m x^{(i)} $$ To determine whether this estimator is biased, we can substitute equation 5.22 into equation 5.20: $$ \begin{aligned} \operatorname{bias}\left(\hat{\theta}_m\right) &
> =\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\theta}_m\right]-\theta \\ & =\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m x^{(i)}\right]-\theta \\ & =\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb{E}\left[x^{(i)}\right]-\theta \\ & =\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{\color{red}{x^{(i)}=0}}^{\color{red}1}\left(x^{(i)} \theta^{x^{(i)}}(1-\theta)^{\left(1-x^{(i)}\right)}\right)-\theta
> \end{aligned} $$

Why do we go from ${x^{(i)}=0}$ to 1? Do we get from the outcome i with 0 probability of outcome to the very sure outcome?

Comment: The ${}^{(i)}$ are indices for the samples $x$. Sometimes they're written as $x_i$, but this might be ambiguous if you also use ${}_i$ to refer to something else.

Comment: @Sycorax - you are correct, though the use of $(1-\theta)^{\left(1-x^{(i)}\right)}$ suggests this superscript in brackets may be also ambiguous when combined with exponents in brackets

Comment: In any case $x^{(i)}$ is simply the value of the $i$th observation, so either $1$ or $0$

Comment: It would be unusual to put an exponent in brackets.

Comment: Okay, got it @Henry ! Nevertheless in $\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{\color{red}{x^{(i)}=0}}^{\color{red}1}\left(x^{(i)} \theta^{x^{(i)}}(1-\theta)^{\left(1-x^{(i)}\right)}\right)-\theta$, what does $\sum_{\color{red}{x^{(i)}=0}}^{\color{red}1}$ stands for? Is it only two elements? Like one whose value is 0, and the other which is one, or the whole set of $\{\color{red}{x^{(1)}, . . . , x^{(m)}}\}$? Because if it is so, then the result of $\sum_{\color{red}{x^{(i)}=0}}^{\color{red}1}\left(x^{(i)} \theta^{x^{(i)}}(1-\theta)^{\left(1-x^{(i)}\right)}\right)$ is the size of the set?

Comment: @Sycorax though $(1-\theta)^{\left(1-x^{(i)}\right)}$ does have an exponent in brackets, so you have to say "if a superscript in brackets is simple like $x^{(i)}$ then it is an index, but if it is complicated like $\phi^{(1-x)}$ then it is an exponent"

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica $\sum_{\color{red}{x^{(i)}=0}}^{\color{red}1}\left(x^{(i)} \theta^{x^{(i)}}(1-\theta)^{\left(1-x^{(i)}\right)}\right)$ $= 0\times \theta^0 (1-\theta)^1 + 1\times \theta^1 (1-\theta)^0 = \theta $

Comment: @Henry I maintain that writing $\phi^{(1-y)}$ is *unusual*, especially because there's no ambiguity to writing the expression as $\phi ^ {1 - y}$, without the parentheses. On the other hand, in this text, the author has decided to use ${}^{(i)}$ to mean an index, which renders $\phi^{(1-x^{(i)})}$ very confusing, because ${a}^{(b)}$ means something different in each case. The wordiness of the explanation in your comment is, I think, a good example of why this chapter's notation is more challenging than it needs to be.

Comment: @Sycorax I totally agree with your final comment.  On the other hand, my use of two subscript indices rather than a subscript and a superscript index was once criticised in the UK House of Lords [16 May 1989, column 111](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Lords/1989-05-16/debates/4a9889b0-b902-4e5b-9be1-99c04696ed20/ElectricityBill), so opinions vary

Comment: @Henry If your typesetting choices bother aristocrats, then I think you're obliged to continue typesetting in that fashion.

Comment: @Sycorax [Lord Peston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Peston,_Baron_Peston) was much more a centre-left academic economist and political adviser than an aristocrat, and in fact the son of a blue-collar textile worker.  I have many more disagreements with economists over how to do and present statistics than I have had with aristocrats.